# Extract accounts from iXBRL file from Companies House

Tags: xml, xbrl

I was able to download a iXBRL file (.xhtml) from Companies House vie their API. Now I am trying to extract individual financial accounts from the file (e.g. cash, assets, etc).

The file is (e.g. https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/09781982/filing-history/MzE4MzYxMDE0MGFkaXF6a2N4/document?format=xhtml&download=1 )

and does not seem to be a XML file. I have tried XML package and it does not work and brings up body and head only:

```
#html is the file    
xml <- xmlParse(html)
xmltop <-xmlRoot(xml) 
xmlSApply(xmltop, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
```

XBRL package does not do well as well, using a local file gives an encoding error and hangs up

```
inst <- file.path("text.xhtml")
xbrl.vars <- xbrlDoAll(inst, verbose=TRUE)
```

Any ideas where to move next or how to get those accounts are highly appreciated

Comment: iXBRL ("Inline XBRL") has a different format than XBRL, so I am not too surprised that the XBRL package failed.

What is the application you're using to load these packages?

Comment: I work in the R Studio, any ideas how to get iXBRL to work? Use a non-R tools?